# How to find $c$? from $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-transformations

How to find $c$? from $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ invertible given by $$T(x,y)=
\left(\begin{array} 
15 & 14 \\
1 & 1 \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array} xx\\ y  \end{array}\right)$$

and $$ T^{-1}(x,y)=\left(\begin{array} aax+by\\ cx+dy  \end{array}\right)  $$

I thought that I could do something like $T\cdot T^{-1}=I(x,y)$ but there is no Identity matrix from that composition, so how should I proceed? Also, I think is not the same $T\cdot T^{-1}$ and $T^{-1}\cdot T$ is it fine?

The other Idea by inverting $T$, I got  $T^{-1}(x,y)= \left(\begin{array}  z1 & -14 \\ -1 & 15 \end{array}\right)  \left(\begin{array} xx\\ y  \end{array}\right)= (x - 14 y, -x + 15 y)$ okay from here $c=-1$.

Comment: "there is no Identity matrix" Oh yes there is. You've got the right idea, just get on with it and do the sums.

Comment: @ancientmathematician If I get the inverse of the matrix, that should be $T^{-1}$ right? I think this way is easier, then just mulltiply it by ${(x,y)}$.

Comment: @Valent That works too. :) (If you think for a moment you'll see that $c$ is going to have to be the bottom-left entry of the matrix for $T^{-1}$, so really you only need to compute that, if you like.)

Comment: Note that you have a typo, $c y + d y$ should of course be $c x + d y$.